# SimpleCartJS: Add CSS classes to generated cart table - displaying a custom cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, simplecart

I'm trying to figure out how to add css classes to the cart table that [SimpleCartJS](http://simplecartjs.org/) generates. (The cart layout I'm using is this: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/shopping-cart-bs-3 but it doesn't really matter)

============

## input

This is my js configuration:

```
simpleCart({
    checkout: {
      type: "PayPal",
      email: "you@yours.com"
    },
    cartStyle: "table", 
    cartColumns: [
    /* Picture (same for every product right now) */
        { view: function( item, column) {
            return "<a class=\"thumbnail pull-left\" href=\"#\"> "
            +"<img class=\"media-object\" src=\"http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-2/72/product-icon.png\" "
            +"style=\"width: 72px; height: 72px;\"> </a>";
            }, label: false },
    /* Name */
        { attr: "name", label: "Product" },
    /* Quantity */
        { attr: "quantity" , label: "Qty" } ,
    /* Price */
        { attr: "price" , label: "Price", view: 'currency' } ,
    /* Remove */
        { view: "remove" , text: "Remove" , label: false }
        ]
  });
```

and my HTML:

```
<div class="simpleCart_items"></div>
```

============

## output

[image]

Basically the output is a generic table.

============

## How do I:

1. Turn `<table>` into `<table class="table table-hover">` ?
2. Add these rows **under** the simpleCart_items?

I'd like these to be rows under all the items:

```
<tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td><h5>Subtotal</h5></td>
    <td><div class="simpleCart_total"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td><h5>Estimated shipping</h5></td>
    <td><div class="simpleCart_shipping"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td><h3>Total</h3></td>
    <td><div class="simpleCart_grandTotal"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_checkout">Checkout</a></td>
</tr>
```

so it'd end up looking something like:

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*useful link:*
https://github.com/wojodesign/simplecart-js/issues/362

**TL;DR**

1. Go to your simplecart.js
2. Search for `items: function (selector)`
3. after `simpleCart.writeCart(selector);` add in a new line `simpleCart.trigger("afterCreate");`
4. add a new bind:

   ```
   simpleCart.bind("afterCreate", function(){
      $cart_table = $(".simpleCart_items table")
      $cart_table.addClass("table").addClass("table-hover")
   });
   ```

   you can add here all you want as always >:3!

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue inspired by previous comments, without editing the actual simplcart.js file:

First hack simpleCart by adding the afterCartCreate event:

```
    var originalMethod = simpleCart.writeCart;
    simpleCart.extend({
      // write out cart
      writeCart: function (selector) {
        originalMethod(selector);
        simpleCart.trigger('afterCartCreate');
      }
  });
```

than just bind to the event:

```
simpleCart.on('afterCartCreate',function (){
    console.log("After create");
    $('.simpleCart_items table').addClass('table');
    $('.item-decrement a').addClass('btn').addClass('btn-default');
    $('.item-increment a').addClass('btn').addClass('btn-default');
  });
```

and voila ;)

Answer (score 2):

In you css add

`.simpleCart_items table {
width:100%;
}`

This should extend the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the simplecartjs.org cart. The configuration is in the footer. You can use a function to create custom cart views. You can add this to the cart columns array.

```
simpleCart({
    currency: "RUB",
    cartColumns: [
    { view: "image" , attr: "thumb", label: false },        
    { attr: "name" , label: "Name" },

    { view: function(item, column){
        return   "<img src='"+ item.get('thumb')+"' alt='product' />" +"<span class='item-format'>"+item.get('total')+"</span>";
    }, attr: 'custom' }

    ],
    cartStyle: "div"
});
```

Also this is discussed in the [documentation here](http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/cart_columns)